# Linux command to copy recently created/updated files?

Tags: shell

I want to copy recently created/updated files to another folder. Say, for eg, the files which created in last 3 days should be copied to another folder(/tmp). how to do that? Is it possible.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you specifically want to update all changed files, it might be better to use [rsync (manpage)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). Otherwise, it is certainly doable using ``find`` and ``xargs`` and ``scp`` (for example), but it seems off topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command's `mtime` argument to find files that were last modified by a certain time and then use it's `exec` argument to copy them somewhere.

For example, this command will find files modified within three days in your current directory and copy them to your `/tmp` directory:

```
find . -mtime -3 -type f -exec cp "{}" /tmp \;
```

> -mtime n File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago. See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the
>   interpretation of file modification times.
>
> -exec command ; Execute command; true if 0 status is returned. All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command
>   until an argument consisting of ';' is encountered. The string '{}' is
>   replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs
>   in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is
>   alone, as in some versions of find. Both of these constructions might
>   need to be escaped (with a '\') or quoted to protect them from
>   expansion by the shell. See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the
>   use of the -exec option. The specified command is run once for each
>   matched file. The command is executed in the starting directory. There
>   are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action;
>   you should use the -execdir option instead.